# complile error in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Typescript.

I wrote the code below today and I got this compile error in my editor.

> Type 'EngineFactory' is not assignable to type
>   'EngineInterface'.  Property 'run' is missing in type 'EngineFactory'.

I understand what this error message means but I don't know how to fix this error. Please teach me the appropriate way to fix this error.

```
interface EngineInterface {

    run();

}


class HondaEngine implements EngineInterface{

    constructor() {}

    run() {}

}


class ToyotaEngine implements EngineInterface{

    constructor() {}

    run() {}

}

enum EngineType {

    Honda,
    Toyota

}


class EngineFactory {

    constructor(engineType: EngineType){

        if (engineType === EngineType.Honda) {
            return new HondaEngine();
        }

        if (engineType === EngineType.Toyota) {
            return new ToyotaEngine();
        }

    }

}



class Car {

    private engine: EngineInterface;

    constructor(engineType: EngineType) {
        this.engine = new EngineFactory(engineType);
    }

}



let car = new Car(EngineType.Toyota);
```

**NOTE**

Writing code this way below results in no compile error.
But I wonder if there is another way to fix the error that I pasted above.

```
class EngineFactory {

    constructor(){}

    static getEngine(engineType: EngineType): EngineInterface {

        if (engineType === EngineType.Honda) {
            return new HondaEngine();
        }

        if (engineType === EngineType.Toyota) {
            return new ToyotaEngine();
        }
    }
}

class Car {

    private engine: EngineInterface;

    constructor(engineType: EngineType) {
        this.engine = EngineFactory.getEngine(engineType);
    }

}


let car = new Car(EngineType.Toyota);
```

I wish I could define the returned type in constructor method...

```
class EngineFactory {

    // Typescript won't let me define returned type in constructor.
    constructor(engineType: EngineType): EngineInterface{

        if (engineType === EngineType.Honda) {
            return new HondaEngine();
        }

        if (engineType === EngineType.Toyota) {
            return new ToyotaEngine();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's meaningless to return a object in constructor function.
2. It would be more clear if you write code this way:

   class EngineFactory {
       constructor(){}

   ```
   static getEngine(engineType: EngineType): EngineInterface {
        switch(EngineType):
              //case  ....
   }
   ```

   }